# Unable to set Access-Allow-Control-Origin in AWS api-gateway for CORS - returns invalid format error

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am having trouble with setting up CORS on AWS API-Gateway.

To provide a bit of background, CORS on API_gateway supports 6 fields as below.

Access-Allow-Control-Origin - supports `'https://www.example.com'`, `'*'`, `'https://*'`, and `'http://*'`

I got this from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html

When I try `'*'` and `'https://www.domain-name.com'`, I get the following errors:

[image]

I am not sure what format to follow. Also, the `'*'` seems to be referenced in various links.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try adding `'*'` directly on the Api Gateway console ?

Comment: The `*` wildcard is disallowed if you have things configured to included credentials in the request and response (that is, cookies and the Authorization request header).

Comment: @ArunK same result. Dev console on the browser tells me "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: @sideshowbarker no cookies are enabled and no authorization request header present. This request is actually a login request.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled cors on your api gateway, the next place to look is the application code such as lambda.

Make sure the Lambda is returning the correct cross origin headers in both successful and failure scenarios. please check if your code is returning cross origin headers all the time.

To troubleshoot,

**Method 1:**
Check if the request is reaching the lambda from the cloud watch logs. You can find some useful information such as exceptions thrown by the code.

**Method 2:**
Point the Api gateway target to the Mock integration type. If the mock integration works, then the problem is the application code. otherwise the problem is in your api gateway end point.

Also note that any headers you use should be white listed in the Access-Control-Allow-headers section when you enable to cors for your method/resource.

Comment: Hello Arun, I do not think the application code is to blame as it seems to be working with http versions of the backend for CORS enabled endpoints. I think this might be purely a AWS API-Gateway issue as it does not seem to recognize the format for the origin that is being entered.

Comment: can you just try `'*'` for origin. if it doesnt work, i need a screenshot, because its working for me